# Perform a sequence of two mouse clicks

Tags: autohotkey

I try to automate a process where I have to perform two mouseclicks. One should go to an absolute position and perform a left click:

```
Click, 492, 256, Right
```

And the second should select a value from the dropdown box. The exact (absolute) location of the value in the dropdown list which should be selected is:

```
Click, 801, 571, Left
```

I hacked together this code:

```
#r::
   Click, 492, 256, Right
   Sleep 1000
   Click, 801, 571, Left
```

But this does not seem to work. It performs a left click at in the situation I want but the dropdown box is not selected. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong at the second Click?

Comment: Use the Window Spy utility. It will show the mouse position relative to the active window and to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the dropdown box doesn't allow "instantaneous" clicks, I had this problem also some time ago. My first post here, so sorry if format is bad...Try the following:

```
  #r::

   Click, 492, 256, Right
   Sleep 1000
   MouseMove, 801, 571
   Sleep 100 ; if code works, try to deactivate this one
   Click, Down Left
   Sleep 100  
   Click, Up Left
```

If this doesn't work:

- Try to lower Speed on MouseMove somewhat, via additional option.
- Try changing SendMode to Input for this part of your script